# Extract data based on two tables with a column data at row level from table 1 and column data at columnar level from table 2

Tags: sql, crud

I want to do a select operation between two tables where a single column data from table 1(l_id)  is spread into multiple columns in table 2(g_id, p_id), how to write the query

table 1

```
e_id, name, l_id
123    dog   789
123    cat   543
123    owl   602
```

table 2

```
f_id, e_id, g_id, p_id
098    123   789   543
099    123   602   602
100    123   543   543
101    123   543   789
102    123   789   789
```

I want to get the name field from table1 as main output in such a way that g_id corresponding name and p_id corresponding name into seperate columns like below.

output:

```
e_id, g_name, g_id, p_name, p_id
123     dog    789   cat     543
123     owl    602   owl     602
123     cat    543   cat     543
123     cat    543   dog     789
123     dog    789   dog     789
```

I tried Union ALL, OR operator but this is just a sub query and J have another table to make a join operation to get a entirely different data. Please help on how to perform JOIN on this scenario. Looking for more of a JOIN operation.

Comment: [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: @ThomA , Thanks for letting me know .will try not to tag in future

Comment: You've not understood the linked Q&A then; you still need to tag but don't *spam* those tags with conflicting technologies. You still need to tag what you are *really* using.

Answer (score 1):

You're just after a normal join - only you need to join the same table twice; once for `p_id` and once for `g_id`:

```
select t2.e_id, tg.name g_name, t2.g_id, tp.name p_name, t2.p_id
from table2 t2
inner join table1 tg on tg.l_id = t2.g_id
inner join table1 tp on tp.l_id = t2.p_id
```

[db-fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/3ZT_-5be)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to joins.

```sql
select t2.e_id,
    t1g.name g_name,
    t2.g_id,
    t1p.name p_name,
    t2.p_id
from table2 t2
join table1 t1g on (t1g.l_id = t2.g_id and t1g.e_id=t2.e_id)
join table1 t1p on (t1p.l_id = t2.p_id and t1p.e_id=t2.e_id)
```

It is not clear if `e_id` could be different, so I through it to join's on clause just in case.